# advanced unset the value form array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, recursive-datastructures, array-unset

I have two arrays, what consist arrays. I need to merge these arrays recursive. But I  need to do this action few times, and

`array_merge_recursive()`

will apend my data twice, I want to remove element what already exist in target array.
$messages array :

```
array(2) {
   ["messages"]=>
       array(2) {
           ["test.testik"]=>
           string(13) "Це тест"
           ["test2313.tes31231tik"]=>
           string(23) "це тестончик"
       }
   ["validators"]=>
      array(4) {
           ["valid.validik"]=>
           string(36) "Це валідне значення"
           ["joga.jimbo"]=>
           string(27) "Джімбо торбінс"
           ["validka.invalidka"]=>
           string(23) "це інвалідка"
           ["smith.john"]=>
           string(17) "джон сміт"
     }
 }
```

$allCar array:

```
array(2) {
      ["messages"]=>
          array(1) {
             ["test2313.tes31231tik"]=>
             string(23) "це тестончик"
            }
      ["validators"]=>
           array(2) {
              ["validka.invalidka"]=>
              string(23) "це інвалідка"
              ["smith.john"]=>
              string(17) "джон сміт"
         }
      }
```

I wrote some code:

```
foreach ($messages as $domain => $messagesArray) {
            foreach ($allCat as $d => $mess) {
                if ($domain == $d) {
                    foreach ($messagesArray as $ymlkey => $trans) {
                        foreach ($mess as $ymlk => $transl) {
                            if ($ymlkey == $ymlk) {
                                unset($mess[$ymlk]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Then when I run recursive merge it append the same values to array. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You'll need to give your starting arrays and expected result.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I added array what need to be compaerd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
        foreach ($allCat as $d => $mess) {
```

$mess is a temporary **COPY** of whatever value your foreach() loop is currently working on. When you do your `unset($mess...)` later on, you're simply unsetting that temporary copy.

While some might suggest making `$mess` a reference, this can/will cause problems later on, because $mess will STILL be a reference after the loops end, and reusing the variable later on will now be mucking around with whatever $mess last pointed at in the loop.

Instead, use the full array/object path reference in the unset call:

```
unset($messages[$domain][$d][$ymlkey][$ymkl])
```

or whatever it should be. This way you guarantee you're working with the actual "real" array, and not any of the many temporary copies your nested loops are creating.

Comment: Serious question:  If you `unset($mess);` wouldn't that not allow it to be used (even as a reference) after the loop completes?  Isn't that the whole point of `unset()`?

Comment: yeah, you could unset $mess directly after the loops, but op's code isn't doing that - just unsetting something INSIDE $mess.

Comment: Ahh, okay.  Totally missed that it wasn't `unset($mess);` but `unset($mess['var'])` instead.  Oops.